# Unity 3d: Prevent Rigidbody from Falling Over

Tags: unity-game-engine, gravity, rigid-bodies

I have a 3d object (army man)  that I  added a RigidBody to. I have a Gun set up that shoots bullets at the army man --- when a bullet hits it, I want it to fall over.  Now I have an issue where as soon as my game starts, my 3d object slowly falls over without any user interaction. I set X and Z freeze positions on the RigidBody but it still falls over. IF I set to freeze on Y position, my 3dObject will not fall over but then if I shoot the army man, it will just spin and not fall over. I attached a screenshot to show all my settings.
[image]

Comment: Try setting Is Kinemetic to true until he gets shot, at that point set it to false.

Comment: @Bryan . That does not work.

Comment: Have you tried disabling gravity until the bullet collides?
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-useGravity.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Collider`'s mesh is obviously standing on a point and is very unstable looking. Either give him a `BoxCollider`, or make a tall rectangle, attach a `Collider` to it and a `RigidBody`, and make the army man mesh a child of it. Remove all colliders and RigidBodies from the army man mesh.

Comment: I tried adding the Box Collider, but the bullets just bounce off and the Army man does not fall over.  I then tried creating a rectangle (Cube) and then added the Army man as a child...  the army man did not fall over initially and I was able to shoot and knock it over, but I need the cube to be transparent without the army man being transparent.

Comment: Yea just remove the box's `MeshRenderer` component

Comment: Honestly all you have to do is give it a `BoxCollider` and in the `BoxCollider` settings in the inspector, you can adjust the size to make it a tall rectangle. Its basically the same thing but without creating a new `GameObject`. The reason it wasn't working before is because its hard to make a bullet knock a cube over, it must be in the shape of a rectangle, preferably top heavy.

Comment: Yep, Removing the box's MeshRenderer component did the trick. I want the hit zone to be a accurate as possible so the BoxCollider may not work for me --- thats why I initially had the Mesh collider on the army man - for better accuracy, but I just couldn't get him to stand up. Thx

Comment: Why not use the actual mesh of the army man as the `MeshCollider`? Yours was a completely different mesh

Comment: How do I "use the actual mesh of the army man as the MeshCollider"?

Comment: It should automatically set it if you add the `MeshCollider` onto your army man. It pulls the mesh from your `MeshFilter` component. Only reason it would be different i think is if you change it afterwards yourself. And by the way, if your going for speed and performance, i wouldn't check `concave`, in your case i'd say that you don't need that feature.

Comment: Also, from looking at your screenshot, i can see that you put the `MeshCollider` onto the parent object, which doesn't contain any of the mesh data. You should either put the `MeshCollider` onto the objects which actually have a `MeshFilter` component, or if your army man is one single mesh, you can probably select it from the list of meshes by clicking the circle next to the `Mesh` option in the `MeshCollider`

Comment: My army man is made up of multiple (15) meshes (it was originally an stl file that was converted). I also tried adding multiple Mesh Colliders with each of the Army mans meshes but still no good -- bullet just passes through

Comment: with `MeshCollider`s on each, and a `RigidBody` on the parent the bullet passes through? Also if its so many meshes, you could just do `BoxCollider`s or `CapsuleCollider`s for each one, with so many parts i'm sure you can already make a pretty complex shape with so many primitives.

Answer (score 3):

In the rigid body you also have the option to freeze rotation around a certain axis:

[image]